# What is so unique about these numbers?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I had read part of this puzzle (can't recall where). I added another part to it. Of course if you have seen this before please let others take a crack at it.

> Why are numbers 1 and 40 uniquely different than all other integers (numbers)?

Please look at the tag before you answer it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> The letters are in alphabetic (FORTY) or reverse-alphabetic (ONE) order.

Comment: [This site](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/numbers.html) makes the same claim for 40. A mental check of 1~20 seems to support the claim for 1. This sounds good to me.

Comment: This is an impressive answer, but I think there is another integer with this property, namely 0. "Zero" is only one of its names. Another one, which can be found in commonly used dictionaries, is "oh".

Comment: @hvd _oh_ is a contraction.

Comment: @Cœur Citation needed. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oh lists it as a complete word.

Comment: *Oh* is indeed a word. And people might use it when writing the speech of someone who says o for the *digit* 0. But dictionary citation, please, for "oh" meaning the *integer* zero.

Answer (score 8):

> The last letter of these numbers can be removed and a word remains.

I could not think of any other numbers that satisfy this criteria. Hint: You only need to check the smaller numbers to see that no other numbers satisfy this condition.

Comment: Interesting. +1 for unique thinking. Note Te is included in many dictionaries as a noun. Ten is the number of course

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I should have said valid Scrabble answers!

Comment: Si also in Dictionaries. My answer is different.

Comment: Si (if you take it be the symbol for Silicon) is a proper noun. But here: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/si "si is the syllable used for the seventh tone of a scale and sometimes for the tone B" That's a lower case "s". Uh oh.

Comment: 80 fits this as well.